# Heroku Node App Error: write EPROTO 140592586876736:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: node.js, heroku, graphql, apollo

I got this error once in while when running Node app on Heroku. We use cloudflare certificate. There's currently nothing that we know affects the end users.

However, it distracts the team and I would like to change/fix this if possible. Can someone have any idea? Or whether I should provide more other information? Thanks!

```
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] Error Error while running `getDataFromTree` { Error: Network error: request to https://domain.io/graphql failed, reason: write EPROTO 140592586876736:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1407:SSL alert number 40
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info 
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info     at new ApolloError (/app/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:124:32)
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info     at /app/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1248:45
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info     at /app/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1680:21
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info     at /app/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1679:22
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info     at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info     at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (/app/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1672:26)
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info     at /app/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1175:35
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info   graphQLErrors: [],
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info   networkError:
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info    { FetchError: request to https://domain.io/graphql failed, reason: write EPROTO 140592586876736:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1407:SSL alert number 40
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info    
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info        at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/isomorphic-unfetch/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1345:11)
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info        at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:391:9)
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info        at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:431:12)
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info        at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:456:5)
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info        at _destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:40:7)
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info        at TLSSocket.Socket._destroy (net.js:613:3)
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info        at TLSSocket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:32:8)
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info        at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:790:10)
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info      message:
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info       'request to https://domain.io/graphql failed, reason: write EPROTO 140592586876736:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1407:SSL alert number 40\n',
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info      type: 'system',
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info      errno: 'EPROTO',
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info      code: 'EPROTO' },
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info   message:
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] error    'Network error: request to https://domain.io/graphql failed, reason: write EPROTO 140592586876736:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1407:SSL alert number 40\n',
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info   extraInfo: undefined,
Dec 2 07:22:48 app[web] info   queryErrors: [ [Circular] ] }
```

Comment: Hi @knd did you find any solution fo this because I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: same issue @aashirkhan any solution?